# Problem on functions.

Tags: calculus, functions

If there are two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ such that 
 $f''(x)= -f(x)$ and $g(x) = f'(x)$ 
and $$F(x) = (f(x/2))^2 + (g(x/2))^2$$
and given that $F(5) = 5$ then $F(10) =$ ?

Comment: This is what I tried- $g(x) = f'(x)$ which implies $g'(x) = f"(x)$. I substituted this in the other eqn to get $g'(x) = -f(x)$ which I integrated but couldn' proceed further.

Comment: Anshuman, I notice that you have asked four questions on this site, but have never selected an answer to any of your questions. If you find an answer helpful, please click on the checkmark next to the answer you deem worthy.

Comment: I didn't notice that I can do that. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have $F(x)=[f(x/2)]^2+[g(x/2)]^2$.

Then
\begin{align}
F'(x)&=2\cdot f(x/2)\cdot f'(x/2)\cdot\frac{1}{2}+2\cdot g(x/2)\cdot g'(x/2)\cdot\frac{1}{2}\\
&=f(x/2)\cdot f'(x/2)+g(x/2)\cdot g'(x/2)\ .\tag{1}\label{1}
\end{align}
We know that $f''(x)=-f(x)$, so $f(x)=-f''(x)$. Also, you wrote that $g(x)=f'(x)$ implies $g'(x)=f''(x)$.

Substituting these results into \ref{1}...
\begin{align}
F'(x)&=f(x/2)\cdot f'(x/2)+g(x/2)\cdot g'(x/2)\\
&=-f''(x/2)\cdot f'(x/2) + f'(x/2)\cdot f''(x/2)\\
&=0
\end{align}

We have that $F'(x)=0$, so $F(x)$ is a constant.

Since $F(5)=5$, we have that $F(x)=5$ and thus $F(10)=5$.